Can I have 2 ratelimit policies in my yarp route
Suppose I have this route in my YARP config .
  "AlgoOmsRoute": {
    "ClusterId": "mycluster",
    "RateLimiterPolicy": "policy1",

    "Match":{
      "Path": "/api//{**catch-all}"
    },
    "Transforms": [
      {
        "PathRemovePrefix": "/oms"
      }
    ]
  }

suppose I have another policy called policy2.
How can I apply both routes in my setting?
  "AlgoOmsRoute": {
    "ClusterId": "mycluster",
    "RateLimiterPolicy": "policy1",
    "RateLimiterPolicy": "policy2",
    "Match":{
      "Path": "/api//{**catch-all}"
    },
    "Transforms": [
      {
        "PathRemovePrefix": "/oms"
      }
    ]
  }

I am using .NET core

According to this setion, it looks like there's no option for setting 2 RateLimiterPolicy, but we could set multiple Routes such as AlgoOmsRoute1 and AlgoOmsRoute2, maybe we could set different RateLimiterPolicy in 2 routes but keep other settings unchanged. May I know whether you try it before? I didnt' test in my side yet, just my assumption.
